# Change power icon's location in the Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu

I recently installed Windows 10 and began making some performance tweaks to speed up my experience slightly.

In a [how-to guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/197836/8-ways-to-customize-the-windows-10-start-menu/) I notice that the screenshots had a power icon at the top right of the start menu as shown in the image below.

[image: Start menu with power icon visible]

I have searched around but can't find how change this for my self.

Can someone provide me with how I can have mine setup in the same way, please?

Comment: The screenshot isn't from a virgin start menu, it is created from a third-party application, what "how to guide' are you speaking of?

Comment: The tutorial never mentions how to make that tweak so you may be right. http://www.howtogeek.com/197836/8-ways-to-customize-the-windows-10-start-menu/

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have a power menu, but i am wanting to emulate what is shown in the screenshot. I dislike it being so close to the apps menu.

Comment: Would be nice to know what your start menu looks like currently

Comment: It's at default at the moment.

Comment: Well my default on every Windows 10 device, is the power button, at the bottom.  So the screenshots are either with a start menu third-party application or there is something else going on.  I have both tablet based devices and non-touched based devices so it isn't that.

Comment: I know they it defaults to the bottom, I'm looking for instruction on how to get it to the top. I assumed it would be a setting as it was visible in a beginners tutorial. If it's not then I'll have to carry on as I am

Comment: this screenshot is from an early Technical Preview (98xx Builds) that had this first startmenu which is now released for WindowsRT 8.1 users.